# Did Ellen G White say Israel will never become a nation

Tags: prophecy, israel, seventh-day-adventists, ellen-g-white

I have been searching high and low for an accredited source that says Ellen G White  said Israel will never become a nation.  Not surprisingly, such a prophetic word would not be easy to find.

I need this information for an assignment I've been given.  It has nothing to do with right or wrong, or "truth", but is simply a genuine request for help with my research.

Any insights/references would be most helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: Are there less reliable sources that claim she said this?

Comment: Recently I was given a printed card that encouraged the reader to do some research into the teachings of the Seventh Day Adventists. It gave three examples of what Ellen G White claimed/taught, and that was one of them. However, the link provided on the card did not give an explicit reference to any of her writings about Israel, or claims that Israel would never become a nation.  The official SDA web site gives only the most basic outlines of what they believe, with no mention of Israel: https://www.adventist.org/beliefs/fundamental-beliefs/

Comment: Are you interested in Biblical sources?

Comment: I have read SDA literature that presents their interpretation of biblical verses that lead them to conclude God has finished with Israel as a nation and that the SDA are now the "true Israel". This question, however, is not asking for justification of the teaching. There are other denominations with similar claims. That subject is for another question and would have to be denomination-specific. This question merely seeks official verification as to what Ellen G. White claimed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went to this official, accredited SDA web-site for this information, where SDA officials respond to more difficult questions about their founder, Mrs. Ellen G. White, that are not generally tackled in other official web-sites. https://whiteestate.org/legacy/issues-faq-unus-html/#unusual-section-d2 There was a question, “Jerusalem Never to be Rebuilt?” that seemed a potential source of information, and so it was.  This is, indeed, directly related to whether she said Israel would never become a nation. She wrote in 1851 that

> “old Jerusalem never would be built up.” [1]

The site responded to this by saying:

> “…we find Mrs. White counseling the growing Adventist group that both
>   time-setting [2] and the "age-to-come" notion [3] were incompatible
>   with Biblical truth. She emphasized that the Old Testament prophecies
>   regarding the establishment of a Jewish kingdom in Palestine were
>   conditional on obedience and forfeited by disobedience. Unfulfilled
>   prophecies would be fulfilled to "true Israel" as unfolded in the New
>   Testament text. Thus the popular movement of the 1840s and 1850s to
>   promote a Zionist state in Palestine was not a fulfillment of Biblical
>   prophecy and not a quest in which Adventists should become involved.
>   Her warnings and instruction were designed to turn the interest away
>   from Palestine and toward the work God had opened up before them. In a
>   September 1850 vision she saw that it was a "great error" to believe
>   that "it is their duty to go to Old Jerusalem, and think they have a
>   work to do there before the Lord comes. . . ; for those who think that
>   they are yet to go to Jerusalem will have their minds there, and their
>   means will be withheld from the cause of present truth to get
>   themselves and others there." [4] Less than a year later, August 1851,
>   she wrote with greater emphasis "that Old Jerusalem never would be
>   built up; and that Satan was doing his utmost to lead the minds of the
>   children of the Lord into these things now, in the gathering time, to
>   keep them from throwing their whole interest into the present work of
>   the Lord, and to cause them to neglect the necessary preparation for
>   the day of the Lord." [5]
>
> [1] Early Writings, p. 75. This sentence appears in the chapter, "The
>   Gathering Time," which combined two visions and some additional lines.
>   The first vision, Sept. 23, 1850,  dealt with the "gathering time" of
>   "Israel," the dates on the Millerite 1843 chart, the "daily,"
>   timesetting, and the error of going to Old Jerusalem. The second
>   vision, June 21, 1851, focused on the third angel's message,
>   time-setting, and Old Jerusalem's not being built up.
>
> [2] Many former Millerites were setting various dates for the return
>   of Jesus, with 1850 and 1851 being the latest dates for the end of the
>   2300-day/year prophecy. Although Sabbatarian Adventists generally were
>   immune from time-setting, Hiram Edson and Joseph Bates advocated 1850
>   and 1851, respectively. James White kept their views out of Present
>   Truth, the Advent Review, and the Review and Herald.
>
> [3] With several variations, age-to-come exponents, led by Joseph
>   Marsh, O. R. L. Crosier, and George Storrs, believed that the Second
>   Advent would usher in the millennial kingdom on earth during which
>   time the world would be converted under the reign of Christ, with the
>   Jews playing a leading role. This group closely related to the
>   Literalists (British Adventists) who had believed that in the 1840s
>   the literal Jews would welcome their Messiah (Christ) in Palestine,
>   thus fulfilling Old Testament prophecies with Jerusalem becoming
>   Christ's capital during the millennium. The majority of the Millerites
>   had rejected this aspect of their Adventist theology, calling it
>   Judaism. (See Josiah Litch, "The Rise and Progress of Adventism," The
>   Advent Shield and Review, May 1844, p. 92, cited in Seventh-day
>   Adventist Bible Students' Source Book, p. 513. The first defectors
>   from early Seventh-day Adventists were H. S. Case and C. P. Russell
>   who had, among other concepts, embraced the "age-to-come" theory. See
>   The Seventh-day Adventist Encyclopedia, s.v. "Messenger Party."
>
> [4] Early Writings, p. 75. [5] Early Writings, pp. 75, 76

(I have included the footnotes as they are important for a full understanding.)

From this it can be seen that SDA “Restorationist” doctrine accounts for the view that God was now dealing with ‘spiritual Israel’ (the Christian Church – themselves) and all the prophecies would be fulfilled in them, not literal Israel, which had forfeited its right to be established in the land. It appears that, due to these two visions of Mrs White, she discouraged SDAs from looking for a re-establishment of Israel because God was now dealing with them. Thus, “old Jerusalem never would be built up”, the SDAs claiming to be “new Jerusalem”. This equates with the idea that old Israel was not going to figure in God’s future plans for a nation like it had been before. The SDAs were the “new Israel” now.

Comment: Not the SDAs but everyone who follows everything the Bible says are Spiritual Israel

Comment: Not to disagree, for as Gal. 6:15 states, "for in Christ Jesus neither circumcision availeth anything, nor uncircumcision, but a new creation; and as many as by this rule do walk, peace upon them, and kindness, and on the Israel of God." However, my point relates to all who believe "Restorationist" theology - that their little group has replaced natural Israel in the promises of God, implying that any others cannot be new creations in Christ and so not part of the spiritual Israel of God. I gather that SDAs & some other groups take that view.

Comment: SDAs do not take that view. We have one creed "Bible". So, we believe that anyone who follow the Bible, are part of the spiritual Israel

Comment: @One Face - I would appreciate a reference/link to an SDA source that upholds what you said about anyone who follows the Bible is part of "spiritual Israel".

Comment: In the professedly Christian world many turn away from the plain teachings of the Bible and build up a creed from human speculations and pleasing fables, and they point to their tower as a way to climb up to heaven. People hang with admiration upon the lips of eloquence while it teaches that the transgressor shall not die, that salvation may be secured without obedience to the law of God. If the professed followers of Christ would accept God’s standard, it would bring them into unity; but so long as human wisdom is exalted above His Holy Word, there will be divisions and dissension. {CTr 70.4

Comment: At the bedside of the dying no word of creed or controversy is to be spoken. The sufferer is to be pointed to the One who is willing to save all who come to Him in faith. Earnestly, tenderly, strive to help the soul that is hovering between life and death.  {CH 352.3}

Comment: The question is, "What is truth?" It is not how many years have I believed that makes it the truth. You must bring your creed to the Bible and let the light of the Bible define your creed and show where it comes short and where the difficulty is. The Bible is to be your standard, the living oracles of Jehovah are to be your guide. {FW 77.1}

Comment: The Spirit of God was to be poured out upon all flesh. Those who hunger and thirst after righteousness were to be numbered among the Israel of God. "They shall spring up as among the grass, as willows by the watercourses," said the prophet. "One shall say, I am the Lord's; and another shall call himself by the name of Jacob; and another shall subscribe with his hand unto the Lord, and surname himself by the name of Israel." Isaiah 44:4, 5.  {PK 371.2}

Comment: "Wherefore the Son of man is Lord also of the Sabbath." Because the Sabbath was made for man, it is the Lord's day. It belongs to Christ... It points to Him as both the Creator and the Sanctifier... speaking of Israel, He said, "I gave them My Sabbaths, to be a sign between Me and them, that they might know that I am the Lord that sanctify them,"..Eze 20:12... Sabbath is a sign of Christ's power to make us holy. And it is given to all whom Christ makes holy. As a sign of His sanctifying power, the Sabbath is given to all who through Christ become a part of the Israel of God.  {DA 288.2}

Comment: @One Face - Thank you. I also believe Christ Jesus is Lord of the Sabbath, but I don't adhere to SDA beliefs regarding Saturday sabbath keeping. Neither do millions of other born-again Christians. Or Jehovah's Witnesses, who also reckon they have replaced Israel and they are "spiritual Israel". "Following everything the Bible says" is wide open to denominational interpretation and man-made rules. I mention this to point out that God knows who belong to Him and nobody is in any position to judge any one else. Appreciate your input but to continue this would be out of the scope of the question.

Comment: I came across this and find the references by @OneFace don't directly address the question of Lesley. Here is one: "We should not, upon entering a place, build up unnecessary barriers between us and other denominations, especially the Catholics, so that they shall think we are their avowed enemies. We should not create a prejudice in their minds unnecessarily, by making a raid upon them.... From that which God has shown me, a great number will be saved from among the Catholics.—Manuscript 14, 1887."

Comment: A second quotation: Christ did not ordain the plan of salvation for any one people or nation. He said: “I lay down my life for the sheep. And other sheep I have, which are not of this fold: them also I must bring, and they shall hear my voice; and there shall be one fold, and one shepherd.”  (From the Heart pg 126)

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard question to answer as without checking every piece of literature.  I would suggest you go over to [Ellen G. White® Estate](https://whiteestate.org/).

There is also a section where you can ask questions to those who work collating her writings. Arguably the experts in what she wrote.

Israel as a nation does not really appear in Adventist Eschatology.  As [Marco](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/75633/25495) suggested, there is the idea that Israel's work was completed and ceased to be relevant and the Church took on the role of Israel after the time of Christ.